# How to interpret reverse score as dependent variable in a two-way ANOVA

Tags: spss, anova

I have two set of independent variables, a dependent variable. 
The dependency variable is speed taken by each individual to complete a task.

The independent variables are Type of Task, Gender.

For the dependent variable, the speed which is measured as the time duration in minutes is interpreted that a lower speed implies a higher efficiency.

How do I cater for this while conducting a two-way ANOVA analysis in SPSS ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack-Overflow! This question, being a statistics question, is off topic here (we help with programming questions). Recommend you post this in [Cross-Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 0):

In running an ANOVA on these data, you can run it either way, using the time (duration), or transforming that to speed. Since transforming time elapsed to speed involves taking a reciprocal, the transformation is not linear, and the results of the two analyses may not agree. Thus you need to decide which one is the right one for your purposes.